# Select Saved Checkmarked Rows on viewdidload

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a settings page with a long list with checkmark accesories. Users can select as many rows as they want and I have them saving in NSUserDefaults. I want their previous selections to be selected next time they open settings so I've tried this:

```
NSArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"choices"]];

if (array.count !=0) {
    NSLog(@"not empt");
    for (id obj in array) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:obj];
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
    }

}
```

But the app crashes with this error every time:

```
erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite explanatory. NSIndexPaths in UIKit require two indexes one for the section and one for the row. It's [explained here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html)

Assuming you only have one section in your table view:

```
for (id obj in array) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:obj inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}
```

Comment: Getting this now -[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (204883856) beyond bounds (10) for section (0).'